# Kubernetes: run persistent pods cassandra/mysql in Ubuntu servers

Tags: mysql, cassandra, kubernetes, persistent-storage

I'm newbie at kubernetes and I'm having problem to understand how I can run persistent pods (Cassandras ones or mysql ones) in ubuntu servers.

Correct me if I'm wrong, kubernetes can scale up or down the pods when it sees that we need more CPU but we are not talking about static code but data that are present in other nodes. So what will do the pod when it receive the request from the balancer? Also, kubernetes has the power to destroy nodes when it sees that the traffic has reduced, so how we can not lose data and not disturb the environment?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [volumes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/) to map a directory in the container to persistent disks on the host or other storage

Comment: Yeah this work only if kubernates scales vertically but what happens when it does it but horizontally (multiple hosts).